# Querying to fetch data from junction object and Accounts

Tags: junction-object

I have a junction object called "JIRA_Data" and its linked/ related to Accounts. How do I query to fetch data from this relationship. I am trying to extract id,type from Account object and Name from JIRA_Data junction object.

Could anyone assist. Thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on your question? You want all those accounts having records in Junction object `JIRA_Data`. Is it correct?

Comment: @sfdc_sk, yes I am trying to have a column that would tell whether the account has value in JIRA_Data. If so, display that corresponding value from JIRA_Data for that Account..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query with proper relationship name.

```
SELECT id,type, 
       (SELECT Name FROM JIRA_DATA__r)
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN:<AccountIds>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get all Accounts having data in your Junction Object `JIRA_Data` in below way :
`List<Account> accList = [SELECT id,type, (SELECT id, Name FROM JIRA_DATA__r)
FROM Account]`;

Here, `JIRA_DATA__r` is the relationship name. Enter the correct relationship name of your Account and JIRA_Data objects
You can access records of `JIRA_DATA__r` as:

```
for(Account a : accList){
for(JIRA_DATA__c test : a.JIRA_DATA__r){
//logic 
}}
```

Comment: Thanks one more novice question. I am trying to pull these records in Python. 

If I normally pull Accounts data, I would use

sf_data_cursor.bulk.Account.query("""SQL code here""")

How do I query in the above case where I am querying in the junction object. Thanks..

Comment: @darkhorse, I have updated my answer. Please check if it provides the result you want.